# What submit type to use in Gerrit with a branching workflow?

Tags: git, gerrit

**First some information:**

1 base code in master branch

3 branches with projects that use the same base code, but have different looks / and some different code.

**Workflow:**

- Work on branch 1/2/3

  - Not necessary to rebase, just commit and push to remote git rep
  - Review on gerrit and merge
- Work on base code on master branch

  - rebase all branches on master branch
  - push to remote git rep
  - review on gerrit merge/rebase

So my question is:
What Submit type is the best fit for this kind of workflow?

- Fast forward only
- merge if necessary
- Rebase if necessary
- Always merge
- Cherry pick

Comment: This would be a nice question example here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops